# If f is a measurable function with $\int_{[0,1]}(f(x))^{2} dm(x) < \infty$ then $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)| dm(x) < \infty$.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need to prove that if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function with $\int_{[0,1]}(f(x))^{2} dm(x) < \infty$ then $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)| dm(x) < \infty$.

I've started by saying that over the set $E=\{x\in [0,1] : |f(x)| \leq (f(x))^{2}\}$ we have $\int_{E}|f(x)| dm(x) \leq \int_{[0,1]}(f(x))^{2} dm(x) < \infty$ by monotonicity.

Now let $x \in E^{c} \cap [0,1]$ so that $|f(x)| > (f(x))^{2}$.

Then we must have $|f(x)|<1$ so by monotonicity $\int_{E^{c} \cap [0,1]}|f(x)|dm(x)<1$.

$E$ and $E^{c}$ are disjoint measurable sets by the measurability of $f$, so:

$\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)| dm(x) = \int_{E}|f(x)| dm(x) + \int_{E^{c} \cap [0,1]}|f(x)| dm(x)$
$\leq  \int_{[0,1]}(f(x))^{2}dm(x) + 1 < \infty$

I'm not sure if the my attempt at the proof is correct, and I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look and let me know if its right, and if I would need to add any further justification.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks, but Cauchy Schwarz isn't something that has been taught on the module I am practicing for, and it doesn't tell me whether my argument above is correct or not.

Comment: Your proof is correct - you could neaten it a little, but that's a question of taste. If you've previously established that $\int fg$ is an inner product on $L^2$ then the above comment is a quick way to show this.

Comment: Your attempt is correct. A useful theorem which can be proven using methodology similar to this goes like this. Let $p>q \geq 1$. 1. If $m(X)<\infty$ then $L^p(X) \subset L^q(X)$. 2. If there exists $c>0$ such that for every $A$ such that $m(A)>0$ you have $m(A)>c$, then $L^q(X) \subset L^p(X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar approach to yours: First off, note that $f(x)^2$ is always $\geq 0$. So $|f(x)|\le f(x)^2$ if and only if $|f(x)|\geq 1$. Also, $f(x)^2<|f(x)|\iff |f(x)|< 1$.

Thus, $$\int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|=
\underbrace{\int_{\displaystyle\{x\in[0,1]\mid |f(x)|< 1\}} |f(x)|}_{\displaystyle< 1} + \underbrace{\int_{\displaystyle\{x\in[0,1]\mid |f(x)|\geq 1\}}|f(x)|}_{\displaystyle\le\int_{[0,1]}f(x)^2<\infty}<\infty.$$

Comment: @badatmath I usually also use this notation, but seeing that OP seems to be learning the basics of measure theory right now, I chose to make it more explicit.