# Inclusion of the $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I learned some of the Lebesgue measure in my analysis class before, however I am still confused over the inclusion of $L^p$ spaces. In my applied math course, I came across the following result

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ be a function defined for all $x \in \Omega.$
If $f \in L^1
(\Omega)$ then we have $f ∈ L^2
(\Omega).$

However I seem to remember showing the following in my analysis class

"If $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function with $\int_{[0,1]}(f(x))^2dm(x)<∞$ then $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|dm(x)<∞.$" (as discussed in this post [If f is a measurable function with $\int_{[0,1]}(f(x))^{2} dm(x) < \infty$ then $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)| dm(x) < \infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3248608))

Which is the opposite inclusion, of the one I am currently studying. It has to do with the fact that omega is open, bounded domain, but I can not remember the specifics of the $L^p$ spaces. What's the logic behind the proof of "if $f \in L^1
(\Omega)$ then we have $f ∈ L^2
(\Omega)?$

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true. Take $1/\sqrt x$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz yes that was my immediate thought too. But isn't there a counter example for the other inclusion as well, 1/x on (1,∞) this of course being an unbounded domain...So the key is that omega is bounded, to have any inclusion
relation between two $L^p$ spaces?

Comment: For bounded spaces, inclusion in one direction is essentially equivalent to convexity and Jensen's inequality, or Hölder's inequality, if you like. For unbounded spaces, there isn't a general inclusion one way or the other, as you pointed out with your example.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz right! So do you think it is likely a typo in my professors stament: $If f\in L^1(\Omega)$ then we have $f\in L^2(\Omega).$?

Comment: I would say it's probably a typo.

Answer (score 3):

> > If $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $L^2(X)\subset L^1(X)$.

$\newcommand\Sqrt[1]{\left(#1\right)^{1/2}}$
Proof: Cauchy-Schwarz: $$\int_X|f|\,d\mu=\int_X1\cdot|f|\,d\mu\le
\Sqrt{\mu(X)}\Sqrt{\int_X|f|^2\,d\mu}.$$

On the other hand note

> > If $\mu$ is counting measure on $X$ then $L^1(\mu)\subset L^2(\mu)$.

(In other words, $\ell^2(X)\subset\ell^1(X)$.)

Hint: Show that $||f||_\infty\le||f||_1$.